# Setting the size of a window in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Fixed: I am trying to create a basic game in [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++) using [OpenGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL). I can make a window with a square in it, and make the square move around. However, I am having trouble getting the window to be the correct size.

If I try and make the window to be 800 by 600 then the window and borders will be this size, not just the bit inside the border. Is there a way I can make it so that the bit inside the border is the size I define?

I pasted the code in http://pastebin.com/jxd5YhHa.

Comment: You can use GetSystemMetrics (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the size of different parts of the window border depending on the style you use.  Then add that to your target client size (800x600) to get your window size.

Comment: It looks like you left a thought unfinished? `Is there any way I can make it so that the ...`?

Comment: oops thanks justed edited it

Comment: How about you show us some code? Your problem sounds like you didn't set viewport and projection correctly. Hard to tell without code though.

Answer (score 0):

After skimming over your code I saw a lot of the typical newbie mistakes – this time low level Win32 API style.

First and foremost: Do yourself a favor and please don't use the naked Win32 API. There are so many nice OpenGL frameworks, which have the added benefit of making your program cross plattform for free. In your case I'd recommend SDL, available from http://www.libsdl.org

Now the main problem with your program is, that it scattered some vital OpenGL operations all over the place. Most importantly setting up viewport and matrices. Your drawing functions should always follow the following scheme

```
void draw(…)
{
    glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);

    glClearColor(…);
    glClearDepth(…);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    for(subview in views) {
        glViewport(…);
    #ifdef USE_FIXED_FUNCTION_PIPELINE
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        projection_setup();

        for(model in scene) {        
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glLoadIdentity();
            modelview_setup();
        #else
            glUseProgram(…);
            setup_uniforms();
        #endif
            draw_stuff();
        }
    }

    SwapBuffers();
}
```

The key here to your problem is, to setup viewport, projection and modelview *in the drawing code* right when you need it to what you need it to be.